# Why indexFor method of HashMap is removed in Java 8

Tags: java

In Java 7 there is `indexFor` method in HashMap which returns the index for hashcode

```
/**
 * Returns index for hash code h.
 */

static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

But in Java 8 I didn't find this method and I didn't find any method that has the same behaviour like indexFor.

How the index for hashcode is calculated in HashMap in Java 8?

Comment: `indexFor` where you find it? I searched in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and it doesn't exist

Comment: *If* it exists, it's not a public method, so it's not part of the API of the class, so you can't use it. How would such a method be useful anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In Java 8, the method is inlined. put(), get(), directly use `(n - 1) & hash`.

Comment: I was curious about this so I looked at the Java 7 sources. The OP had posted the actual method declaration so it wasn't public.

Comment: although it is not public it is used with in the class  in put and get methods to find the index of bucket to  perform  insertion or retreival                                                            http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: Hey JB Nizet thank you for providing me a hint on how put and get works internally

Answer (score 0):

This is the best blog which explained the internals of HashMap how index is calculated based on hashcode , and a lot of  stuff where i found the answer for my question 
https://deepakvadgama.com/blog/java-hashmap-internals/